Set the position of a box() in shinydashboard body
How can I place a box() exactly in the middle of shinydashboard body height and stuck to the most left side of the body next to the sidebar?
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Connected Boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      # Empty column to offset box to the center
      column(1, offset = 0),
      box(
        title = "Middle Box",
        width = 1,
        height = 200,
        style = "background-color: #f9f9f9; border-color: #dddddd;"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)


A solution is to adjust the column size from 1 to 6 as demonstrated in the following code:
column(6,offset = 0)

Take note that the combined sizes of the columns in fluidRow() cannot exceed 12. This means that if you want to include 3 columns in your dashboard body, they can only be as follow:
fluidRow(
column(4,. . .)
column(4,. . .)
column(4,. . .) 
)


I hope this is what you are looking for!

and how can I put it lower?
